# no value given fr one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, sql-injection

I'm trying to prevent SQL injections. Am I doing this right? (I'm using MS Access.) Should I still use `sqlparameter`?

```
OleDbParameter[] myparm = new OleDbParameter[2];
myparm[0] = new OleDbParameter("@UserID", UserName.Text);
myparm[1] = new OleDbParameter("@Password", encode);

string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM TMUser WHERE UserID=@UserID AND Password=@Password";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(_connStr);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, conn);

conn.Open();
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close!

```
string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM TMUser WHERE UserID=@UserID AND Password=@Password";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(_connStr);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", encode);
```

The parameters are part of the command object and you use the `Parameters.AddWithValue` method to set the parameter values to what you have defined in the query string.

By the way, you should be using `using` statements to encapsulate some of your objects, here is what I typically do:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(_connStr))
using (OleDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ...";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);

    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    //...
}
```

That way you don't have to worry about cleaning up resources if something goes wrong inside or closing the connection when you are done.